# biblatex, error: \addbibresource{sample.bib} is undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex

**edit:**

i like to learn how to use `biblatex`. for this i installed `biblatex` and in editor (winedt) adjust `biber` as backend. for the test i use the minimal example from [gist.github.com/moewew](https://gist.github.com/moewew/7e4ab47e44702a043f0f94256a20743d) as suggest [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

i immediately obtain error:

```
undefined control sequence
<recently read> \addbibresource

l.54     \addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

i try with pdfLaTeX as well with pdfLaTeXify. in both case i got the same error. i use recent 64-bit MikTeX and recent WinEdt editor.

after compiling with ˙latex`i obtain the following`blg` file:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.12
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'biblatex_test-1.blg'
[44] biber-MSWIN64:315> INFO - === 
[66] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - biblatex_test-1.bcf is malformed, last biblatex run probably failed. Deleted biblatex_test-1.bbl
[66] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

.log file is long, but i thing that relevant part is:

```
(C:/localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2009/07/04 v0.8e biblatex generic definitions
\c@smartand=\count143
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.bbx' found.

(C:/localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\bbx\authoryear.bbx
File: authoryear.bbx 2009/07/04 v0.8e biblatex bibliography style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(C:/localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\bbx\standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2009/07/04 v0.8e biblatex bibliography style
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'authoryear'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'authoryear.cbx' found.

(C:/localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\cbx\authoryear.cbx
File: authoryear.cbx 2009/07/04 v0.8e biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(C:/localtexmf\tex\latex\biblatex\latex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \addbibresource 

l.3 \addbibresource
                   {biblatex-examples.bib}
? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

Comment: The example as posted compiles fine for me and shows a few citations but others are missing. There is no error message about `\addbibresource` for me. Does the `.log` file contain other errors?

Comment: @moewe, i suspect that something is wrong with my installation, but i haven't any clue how to find this. i install all package by help of miktex *console* . i also try to deinstal biblatex and install it again, but no changes. do i need reinstall complete miktex?

Comment: Did you install biblatex as user or as administrator?

Comment: No, don't go on an un- and re-installing rampage before we have analysed the issue. Try a really minimal example like https://gist.github.com/moewew/7e4ab47e44702a043f0f94256a20743d, compile it with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (ideally from the command line, but at least not with TeXify) and upload the *complete* `.log` and `.blg` file to a plain-text sharing website (pastebin, hastebin, GitHub Gists, ...).

Comment: @Bernard, good question. at installation i select that it is only for me, consequently it is installed in "program files" but in users/...AppData/Local/Programs/MikTeX2.9. i'm only user of machine and was till to now convinced that it is installed as "administrator"

Comment: @moewe, i test suggested file. unfortunately i'm not familiar with "plain-text sharing website", so for its use i need more time. for now i added (hopefully) relevant part of `.log` file and complete `.blg` file to my question.

Comment: Whoa. Your `biblatex` is *ancient*. It is version 0.8e from 2009! Apparently you have this very old version in `C:/localtexmf` and that is given precedence over the version installed by MikTeX.

Comment: You should probably remove `biblatex` from `C:/localtexmf`.

Comment: @moewe, you save my life. it seams that i try to learn almost ten year ago to use biblatex, but then forgot on this, but it stay in my `localtexmf`. after removing it all works as desired! thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.log` file shows that you have the ancient `biblarex` v0.8e from July 2009 (more than nine years ago) in your `C:/localtexmf` directory.

Incidentally, this is the oldest version for which I could find sources when I built an archive of older `biblatex` versions and the documentation for that version warns

> Please be advised that this package is in beta stage and released for testing. The version number will be stepped up to 1.0 as soon as it is considered suitable for general distribution.

I assume that `C:/localtexmf` is your local `texmf` tree for experiments and local package installs. That directory is usually given preference over the package versions installed via your TeX distribution. I suggest you remove the manual `biblatex` install in that folder. You may also want to have a look around there for other older versions of TeX packages. Maybe you can sell them to collectors – but at the very least you can make sure that you are not limiting your system to ancient version of actively developed TeX packages.

---

Just for completeness' sake: `\addbibresource` was introduced as replacement for `\bibliography` in version 1.2 of `biblatex` (released in February 2011) according to the extended changelog in `biblatex.tex` (commented out in the PDF version), so one and a half years after your version came out.

Comment: thank you very muchagain. now i will check presence of all (very) old packages collected in `localtexmf`, which i have been used for some test in (far) past.