# How to add list of publication in "thesis" class

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texstudio

[image: screenshot]
[image: main reference list]
[image: Ref appearing as zero]

I am in the process of writing my thesis in LaTeX using TeXstudio. Past two days I am trying to resolve "list of publications" sections using various suggested methods such as,

1. [Tried first and second answer in this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/including-additional-bibliography-publication-list-in-thesis) But it was not working or was showing error.
2. [And finally this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/biblatex-list-of-references-of-own-papers-in-appendix-might-intersect-with-bib)

Here, in this case it is not showing any error and it normally compiled. But there is **no** list of publication printed. What could be the solution?

So far, I have tried **compiling by deleting all auxiliary files**. My bib file name is `RSC.bib` and I am trying to fetch my publications from this main reference file. I am using XeLaTeX compiler.

My MWE is follows:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{thesis}

  \begin{filecontents*}{RSC.bib}

@article{remanan2019preparation,

    title="Preparation and characterization..",

    author="S. {Remanan} and M. {Bose} and A. K. {Das} and N. C. {Das}",

    journal="Journal of Applied Polymer Science",

    volume="136",

    number="12",

    pages="47218",

    notes="Sourced from Microsoft Academic - https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/2898623046",

    year="2019",

    keywords ="myPapers"
}
 \end{filecontents*}


 \usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8,defernumbers, maxnames=99]{biblatex}

 \begin{document}

 \pagenumbering{roman}

 \include{firstpage}

 \include{frontmatter}

 \include{abstract}

 \cleardoublepage

 \tableofcontents

 \include{listofnotation}

 \cleardoublepage

 \listoftables

 \listoffigures

 \pagenumbering{arabic}

 \input{intro}      %%Chapter 1%%

\cleardoublepage

\singlespacing

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\cleardoublepage

\newpage

\printbibliography

 \appendix

\begin{refsection}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword=myPapers,title={My papers}, prefixnumbers={P.}, heading=bibnumbered]

\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a current version of `biblatex` `labelprefix=P` must be given as argument of the `refcontext`. Note that `refcontext`s are not fully supported by BibTeX, but with `biblatex` 3.14 the following will work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{thesis}


\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8, defernumbers, maxnames=99]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{remanan2019preparation,
  title    = {Preparation and characterization},
  author   = {S. Remanan and M. Bose and A. K. Das and N. C. Das},
  journal  = {Journal of Applied Polymer Science},
  volume   = {136},
  number   = {12},
  pages    = {47218},
  notes    = {Sourced from Microsoft Academic - https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/2898623046},
  year     = {2019},
  keywords = {myPapers},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{remanan2019preparation}
\printbibliography

\appendix
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[keyword=myPapers,title={My papers}, heading=bibnumbered]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Assuming the document is saved as `mydoc.tex`, I get a the expected output when I compile the document as follows

```
xelatex mydoc
bibtex mydoc
bibtex mydoc1-blx
xelatex mydoc
xelatex mydoc
```

In particular you need a different BibTeX run for each `refsection` you in your document. (Your document has two: The default `refsection` 0 that is present everywhere and a `refsection` 1 for your list of publications.)

Then I get

[image: A. MY PAPERS//[P1] S. Remanan, M. Bose, A. K. Das, and N. C. Das. “Preparation and characterization”. In: Journal of Applied Polymer Science 136.12 (2019), p. 47218.]

---

Things are much easier if you use the preferred Biber backend (`backend=biber,` instead of `backend=bibtex8,`) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

With

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{thesis}


\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=biber, defernumbers, maxnames=99]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{remanan2019preparation,
  title    = {Preparation and characterization},
  author   = {S. Remanan and M. Bose and A. K. Das and N. C. Das},
  journal  = {Journal of Applied Polymer Science},
  volume   = {136},
  number   = {12},
  pages    = {47218},
  notes    = {Sourced from Microsoft Academic - https://academic.microsoft.com/paper/2898623046},
  year     = {2019},
  keywords = {myPapers},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{remanan2019preparation}
\printbibliography

\appendix
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[keyword=myPapers,title={My papers}, heading=bibnumbered]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

it is enough to compile

```
xelatex mydoc
biber mydoc
xelatex mydoc
xelatex mydoc
```

Comment: @SanjayRemanan Did you make sure to run (or have your editor run) Biber instead of BibTeX (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)? What kind of warnings do you get? Do you also get the warnings when you run the example code from my answer or only if you incorporate the ideas into your big document?

Comment: Hello @moewe Thanks for the help. I used the second method (backend=biber) as you suggested. But while running the "bibliography", a lot of warnings are coming  even though compile process exited normally. While in the main list of bibliography section, only a few reference are appearing those have the same keywords.

WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'ferain2001pore' (section 0) 
......
INFO - WARNINGS: 340
Process exited normally. I got this warning when I incorporated. Will update you. I am working on it :-)

Comment: Seems like at .bib file is not recognizing during compiling. Actually whole main reference list is missing at the end of the pdf and only "list of publication" is coming. In the text instead of numbers cited names are appearing like for example........ [ai2016mos2]. Also   \missing{aid2019on}
  \missing{ajji2003elongational}
  \missing{akthakul2004antifouling}
  \missing{al-shimmery20193d}" this kind of errors are displayed in the  "mydoc (notepad)" file. Seems like reference file is not responding.

Comment: @SanjayRemanan If Biber can't find these references there should be errors or warnings in the `.blg` file. Check that file carefully for errors and try to fix them.

Comment: Hello Moewe,
I couldn't find as you suggested. I have created a new .bib file and copy pasted references and now it is appearing. But few problems like continuous number is missing and display only zero (please see image).

Comment: Also, I removed the "\" before the bib file in the command line. Otherwise it is showing the error that "undefined control sequence". I also find your answer on this problem in one earlier discussion (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467031/biblatex-error-addbibresourcesample-bib-is-undefined-control-sequence), but I think my 'biblatex' is new, and in the 'log' file it appear as ".........v3.14 biblatex......"

Comment: @SanjayRemanan Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean about ```\``` before the `.bib` file in the command line. If you only get "[0]"s for your citations, run XeLaTeX again. With your setup a full compilation sequence involves XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110728/discussion-between-sanjay-remanan-and-moewe).